# making basic string matching based autocomplete using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, node.js, dom

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<style>

</style>
</head>
<body>

<h2>Autocomplete</h2>

<p>Start typing:</p>

<!--Make sure the form has the autocomplete function switched off:-->
<div autocomplete="off" >
  <div class="autocomplete" style="width:300px;">
    <textarea id="myInput" type="text" name="myCountry" placeholder="Country"></textarea>
  </div>
</div>

<script>
function autocomplete(inp, arr) {
  var currentFocus;

  inp.addEventListener("input", function(e) {
  var a, b, i, val = this.value;
  closeAllLists();
  currentFocus = -1;

  // Check if the last character is a backslash
  if (val.slice(-1) === "\\") {
    // Create the autocomplete list
    a = document.createElement("DIV");
    a.setAttribute("id", this.id + "autocomplete-list");
    a.setAttribute("class", "autocomplete-items");
    this.parentNode.appendChild(a);

    // Populate the autocomplete list based on the array
    for (i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
      b = document.createElement("DIV");
      b.innerHTML = "<strong>" + arr[i].substr(0, val.length) + "</strong>";
      b.innerHTML += arr[i].substr(val.length);
      b.innerHTML += "<input type='hidden' value='" + arr[i] + "'>";
      b.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
        // Append the selected suggestion to the existing content
        inp.value += this.getElementsByTagName("input")[0].value;
        closeAllLists();
      });
      a.appendChild(b);
    }
  }
});
  inp.addEventListener("keydown", function(e) {
    var x = document.getElementById(this.id + "autocomplete-list");
    if (x) x = x.getElementsByTagName("div");
    if (e.keyCode == 40) {
      currentFocus++;
      addActive(x);
    } else if (e.keyCode == 38) {
      currentFocus--;
      addActive(x);
    } else if (e.keyCode == 13) {
      e.preventDefault();
      if (currentFocus > -1) {
        if (x) x[currentFocus].click();
      }
    }
  });

  function addActive(x) {
    if (!x) return false;
    removeActive(x);
    if (currentFocus >= x.length) currentFocus = 0;
    if (currentFocus < 0) currentFocus = (x.length - 1);
    x[currentFocus].classList.add("autocomplete-active");
  }

  function removeActive(x) {
    for (var i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
      x[i].classList.remove("autocomplete-active");
    }
  }

  function closeAllLists(elmnt) {
    var x = document.getElementsByClassName("autocomplete-items");
    for (var i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
      if (elmnt != x[i] && elmnt != inp) {
        x[i].parentNode.removeChild(x[i]);
      }
    }
  }

  document.addEventListener("click", function (e) {
    closeAllLists(e.target);
  });
}

var countries = ["Afghanistan","Albania","Algeria","Andorra"];
autocomplete(document.getElementById("myInput"), countries);
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

I have this code for string matching, but it's not effectively providing autocomplete suggestions.Specifically, when I input 'al,' it should return all words containing 'al.' I aim to create an autocomplete function similar to what we find in IDEs, where it suggests word completions based on our input. Could you help me improve my code for this purpose?

I dont want to use libraries like Jquery , please help me with  pure javascript implementation without any library

i have tried my ways and searched internet but did not found anything useful that will help me please help me to figure out whats wrong with my code

Comment: There's two main issues in your code. 1. Your list only gets built if the last character in the `input` is `\` - remove that check, it serves no purpose at all for this use case. 2. You don't filter the list of country names to find only those which contain the entered string.

Comment: can you please help me do that i was trying to make it work from yesterday still not figured it out

Comment: i am at learning phase so i wanna from scratch to learn these and also most of the libraries i seen do not exactly solve my problem  :(

Comment: the code you gave me has same issue as i listed means i want this autocomplete feature to be part of a text editor i will  like it to suggest autocomplete in whole text i am writing

Comment: Sure, this covers those basic issues: https://jsfiddle.net/RoryMcCrossan/uo3nb0fd/. The problem is that your question is too broad as the code has so many other issues, such as highlighting the wrong text in the country list, appending to the textarea and not removing the search text (which itself will be very hard to identify) and sorting the filtered list by best match. I would strongly suggest you use an existing library for this, as all of these problems have already been solved.